# Is it possible to resort a Solr Query with reRank query?

Tags: solr, spring-data

I managed to use reRankQuery and sort the results based on numerical fields. However, I cannot do the same for String fields. Is there a way to do this with reRank query?

I am using Solr v8.2

Comment: Do you have an example of your query and what the error/problem is? There is no inherent limitation in the re-rank query as far as I know that should limit this.

Comment: For example something like the following:                                                           
 {!rerank reRankQuery=$rqq reRankDocs=100 reRankWeight=3}");
  where rqq = (_val_:number) ; will work for numeric fields.                            
However, if I put rqq = (sort name asc) won't work as expected. It won't  resort the results based on the name field.

Comment: But that's not a valid query. The rerankquery needs to be a _valid solr query_. The _score_ of that query is added to the regular query. If you just want sorting, you probably do not need to use the re-rank query at all, since that's a very effective process already for indexed fields. The goal of the re-rank query parser is to limit the use of _expensive functions_, where calling an expensive function on millions of documents might be unnecessary because of other limitations in the query. For regular sorting by indexed values, using the regular `sort` should be enough.

Comment: Mat first of all thank you for your help. Maybe you didn’t understand what I want to do. I am doing a query based on some filters and sorting parameters and then I want to resort the returned results based on another sorting parameter. So what I want is to resort the already sorted results ...If rerank query is not the way to achieve this is there a way?

Comment: For example if the results returned form the first query are 10 objects based on a sorting parameter I want to be able to do a re sorting on these specific 10 objects.

Comment: `sort=fieldA desc, fieldB asc`?

Comment: Not that,because I want the first result set to be returned based on a sorting parameter/s. and then in this exact set to resort the results based on another sorting field. example: I have { 1, "Mar"}, {2, "Alpha"}, {3, "Red"}...from the first query and then I want to resort based on alphabeticall order and have the following ... {2, "Alpha"}, {1 ,"Mar"}, {3, "Red"}.. If I do a query again with the sorting params I want I probably will get another result set...for example {4, "Nik"}, {5, "Sofia"}... but I don't want that.

Comment: It'd be helpful to have an example that includes example documents that shows what's wrong with using a composite sort order like above, but let's try to make it work with rerank instead if that's what you've deemed necessary. How about using a function query with `ord` (which gives you the ordinal of the field in the sorted set) - so either `{!func}ord(field)` or possibly `_val_:ord(field)`? Since rerank-queries are _added to the existing score_ (it's not a sort by definition), you might have to add a large weight as well (either through `product()` or `^<weight>`).

Comment: A composite sort order will always return results based on the order the sorting params are set and what I want is to reorder the elements based on another sorting param.

Comment: Thank you Mat for your help. I managed to sort by using the {!func}(r)ord(field) for the string fields and _val_: field for the numerical fields. The only thing  I am missing is that _val_: field always sort by descending order and I am searching how to perform an ascending order.

Comment: Look at the scores calculated for your entries (append `debug=all`) and adjust accordingly. The limitation of using the rerank functionality is that it'll only _add_ to the score. You can use other mathematical functions (such as sub to subtract, iirc) to instead have a large value and use the ord (or rord) value to subtract from that larger score value.